# Asking a variant of a question

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

I have a question which is based on the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416514/how-to-show-that-if-a-is-compact-dx-a-dx-a-for-some-a-in-a). The question reads:

> Show that if A is compact, show that $d(x,A)= d(x,a)$ for some $a \in A$.

What if I change the question to

> Show that if X is complete and $A \subset X$ is closed, show that $d(x,A)= d(x,a)$ for some $a \in A$.

I'm at a lost here. Can I get a hint? I can't seem to use to hints at the original post. My initial thoughts are to construct a sequence such that it converges to $inf\{d(x,a) | a \in A\}$. However, I need to show that the set $\{d(x,a)|a \in A\}$ contains its $inf$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $A$ is closed then show that for $x \in X$ there exists an element $a_0 \in A$ such that $d(x,A)=d(x,a_0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508937/if-x-d-is-a-complete-metric-space-and-a-is-closed-then-show-that-for-x-i). See also [A counter example of best approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481843/a-counter-example-of-best-approximation/481861#481861).

Comment: In short: "It would be false, absent properties like local compactness or such."